# phpize and php api version doesnt match

Tags: php, memcached, php-extension

I am trying to install `memcached` in my mac. I have downloaded and installed it. I added it to php.ini as well. But still `memcached` doesnt load. I realized that the problem is with the **API** version mismatch of `php` and `phpize`.

This is what I get when I do `php -v`

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: memcached: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.4.8 (cli) (built: Oct 30 2012 19:29:58) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

I would really appreciate if someone would help me fix this issue. Cheers.

Comment: how are you installing PHP and memcached? Are you using a package manager?

Comment: I compiled php manually. But used brew to install memcached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to build the PHP extension manually. The extension you've ended up with is built against the system's copy of PHP 5.3, not your self-installed PHP 5.4.

Comment: I have tried installing manually as well. Will you be kind enough to point me towards right direction.

Comment: Make sure to run the copy of `phpize` that was installed with PHP 5.4, *not* `/usr/bin/phpize`.

Comment: when I do {which php} it shows me /usr/bin/php and {which phpize} returns /usr/bin/php. So I am assuming they are both right. isnt it?

Comment: No. Those paths both refer to the system PHP (5.3).

Comment: I have updated both of my php. They are 5.4.8. thats the phpize -v `Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626`

Comment: PHP API 20090626 is PHP 5.3. If you're still getting that message, you've still using some of the system PHP 5.3 files.

Comment: How does one go about finding the phpize for the 5.4.8 or greater?

Comment: @MikeKormendy: Depends entirely on how you installed it, but it's no different from other versions. It may be part of a separate `php-devel` (or similarly named) package.

Comment: I beleive the phpize was improperly configured and uses an old php install that I nolonger have on the system. I think I have to recompile php and force it to use the current version .. every time I do phpize version it reports for 5.3, but it doesn't exist on the system and all I have now is 5.4.14

Comment: I actually couldnt work out what the actual issue was. I ended up reinstalling the OS, installed PHP again, and installed memcached. No issues at all. So I think previously, there was a conflict with 2 versions of PHP.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you should build the extension manually by the following step

```
phpize
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/php/bin/php-config
make
make install
```

make sure you run `phpize` and `php-config` pointing to your correct php verison.

not in the `/usr/bin/phpize` and `/usr/include/php`

make sure use `--with-php-config`

Comment: thank you very, very much for the `--with-php-config` hint!! Is there any doc where we find out which arguments may be passed to `./configure`?

Comment: @steven `./configure --help`

Answer (score 0):

Download the phpX.X.tgz in accordance to you php version, unzip and copy the files php.z, zend_modules.h, zend_extension.h to the include directory (you could check the correct api version if you edit the file and search for define API_VERSION it's must match with the api number that phpinfo shows)

In other words when you build the extension you must include the correct .h files it's can be obtained from phpxx.tgz sources